# How do I get the distance between two points in meters with different SRIDs in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, distance, srid

I purchased an address-point database (string, geom with SRID 2914) from my local county GIS provider, and I am trying to find the distance between a point in this database and a point with SRID 4326. I've demonstrated what I'm trying to do below in PostGIS.

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
     ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-123.0689666 44.0334234)', 4326), 
     ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-123.0695109 44.0336275)', 2914), 4326))
```

I'm trying to project the point with SRID 2914 to 4326 in order to get the distance between them. These points are very close to each other (no farther than 50m), but I'm getting a large number: 1317988.3361829. It may be that I don't understand coordinate projection very well.

Comment: `'POINT(-123.0695109 44.0336275)'` *cannot* be `EPSG:2914` - its unit is `ft`, and the coordinate values must reflect that - so rn that point is 44**ft** north of the Equator. It looks like it is `EPSG:4326`, too. Apart from that, your query *would* work, given correctly referenced geometries.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, it now does work. How did you know its unit is ft? I'm still kinda confused on how projection works though. I'll go do some more reading. thanks again!

Comment: [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/2914)

Comment: st_distance(st_transform(geom1, 4326)::geography, st_transform(geom2, 4326)::geography) will do what you need.  Transform to geographic coordinates (lat/lon) then cast that to geography type to get length in meters using the spheroid distance.